# phpfox: change new users privacy

Tags: phpfox

I want to set `friends_only` privacy to all new users. I tried `User Default Privacy Setting on Registration` but does not work!
Any Idea??

Thanx

Regards

**Edit:**
There is a simple way to let the user change there privacy after Sign-up by direction them to the privacy page. Example ( `http://localhost/my_network/index.php?do=/user/privacy/` )

Comment: That setting only works for new users. Not for existing ones

Comment: I do that and register new users ... nothing  but it changed only profile privacy  ... I tried it on Wamp server. not on the real site. I google it ... a lot of phpfox admins has the same issue

Comment: What about the "Friends Only Community" setting?

Comment: @Purefan you are awesome. I've been searching for long time. you saved my life. Thank you very much. you can add your answer just to tick it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the setting "Friends Only Community" seems to be what the OP was looking for :) glad I could help